# How to get the implementation type at runtime

Tags: java

I have a iterface called A. Now i derive 3 classes from interface A.

How i can i add some method to the interface like getType() which return me the right type of instance I am dealing with. I don't want to do something like demo instanceOf A in nested if else for checking the instance type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always `.getClass()` which will return the object's `Class`. But it is essentially the same as `instanceof`. You should not need to know the concrete type. Put the logic in each implementation instead. So for example:

```
interface Foo() {
     int calculate();
}

class Bar implements Foo {
     public int calculate() {
        return 1+1;
     }
}

class Baz implements Foo {
     public int calculate() {
        return 2+2;
     }
}

Foo foo = getFoo();
int result = foo.calculate();
```

instead of:

```
Foo foo = getFoo();
int result = 0;
if (foo.getClass().equals(Bar.class)) {
    result = 1+1;
} else of (foo.getClass().equals(Baz.class)) {
    result = 2+2;
}
```

Comment: can u explain me in more detail what u mean by put logic in each type instead.

Comment: Exactly, it sounds like the OP is starting to go down a bad road that is correctly solved using the polymorphism support already in Java.

Comment: @Saurabh Kumar see the simplified example I added

Comment: @saurabh in general it is a sign of bad design if you have to know the implementing class of an interface. From the using class standpoint it should not matter which implementing class it gets as long as it implements the interface.

Comment: I already did the same thing but then I have a UI and there is a mapper class for each of the class derived from A. Now I want to get the right mapper from A for a class derived from A. The mapper class is not derived from A but can i include some method in A which gives me the right mapper type.The mapper is derived from a abstract type.

Comment: define `Mapper getMapper();` in `A` or even put the mapping logic inside a `map()` method.

Comment: I have a abstract mapper from which all the mapper's extend. Can i use this abstract class as Mapper..?